# Custom toolbar button to change value of a field and save form

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, ootb

I've created a SharePoint OOTB list. For that I need to create a custom action button to Ribbon bar. When User clicks that button, it should change the status field of the list and save the form.

Currently I've used SharePoint Designer's custom action feature to add ribbon button & created the workflow to change the status also bind that workflow with that custom button. Its trigger the workflow and the status get changed, but its not save any changes on the form. It simply close the form and started the workflow..

I need that custom button should work like default save button & the status should get changed..

Any help would be appreciated ..

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be like, Take custom ribbon button ID using F12 developer tools and the button click call the JavaScript function to set the field item.

like button id "Ribbon.Library.Share.Button Name"

```
 $("#buttonID").click(function() {

 //Enter the update the field function 
    });
```

and also try this below link,

http://www.a2zmenu.com/Tutorials/SharePoint/How-to-add-ribbon-button-in-SharePoint-list-and-library.aspx

https://raquelalineblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/sharepoint-2013-custom-ribbon-action-to-update-a-list-item-field/